# Meaning of NNI ENAS result

Tags: json, neural-network

I'd like to understanding the result of NNI ENAS macro and micro result.

I faced the problem with ENAS micro result

Below is the result of ENAS NNI macro result

```
{
  "normal_node_0_x_input": 0,
  "normal_node_0_x_op": 0,
  "normal_node_0_y_input": 1,
  "normal_node_0_y_op": 1,
  "normal_node_1_x_input": 1,
  "normal_node_1_x_op": 2,
  "normal_node_1_y_input": 2,
  "normal_node_1_y_op": 4,
  "normal_node_2_x_input": 0,
  "normal_node_2_x_op": 3,
  "normal_node_2_y_input": 0,
  "normal_node_2_y_op": 1,
  "normal_node_3_x_input": 0,
  "normal_node_3_x_op": 3,
  "normal_node_3_y_input": 1,
  "normal_node_3_y_op": 3,
  "normal_node_4_x_input": 0,
  "normal_node_4_x_op": 3,
  "normal_node_4_y_input": 1,
  "normal_node_4_y_op": 4,
  "reduce_node_0_x_input": 1,
  "reduce_node_0_x_op": 1,
  "reduce_node_0_y_input": 0,
  "reduce_node_0_y_op": 1,
  "reduce_node_1_x_input": 0,
  "reduce_node_1_x_op": 0,
  "reduce_node_1_y_input": 1,
  "reduce_node_1_y_op": 3,
  "reduce_node_2_x_input": 0,
  "reduce_node_2_x_op": 2,
  "reduce_node_2_y_input": 1,
  "reduce_node_2_y_op": 3,
  "reduce_node_3_x_input": 2,
  "reduce_node_3_x_op": 3,
  "reduce_node_3_y_input": 3,
  "reduce_node_3_y_op": 1,
  "reduce_node_4_x_input": 0,
  "reduce_node_4_x_op": 3,
  "reduce_node_4_y_input": 2,
  "reduce_node_4_y_op": 3
}
```

My question on "normal_node_0_x_input": 0, "normal_node_0_y_input": 1

I have no idea the index after 'x|y_input: '
Does it mean the node index on normal cell and reduction cell?
If that, node_0_x_input: 0 -> is it fed by it self?

Anybody can clarify this result?